# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module jacksApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to learn Angular and I having trouble getting it to load properly. I took a look at similar questions on SO about this, but could not find what I was looking for.

Does anyone see why this error is occurring? Am I calling my new app/module correctly in my view? Do I have the script wrong? Is the version of Angular I am trying to use not supported? Is there another error in my script?

I can't make it out for some reason.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html ng-app="jacksApp">
    <head>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="mainController">
            <h1>Making an Angular App</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('jacksApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function() {

});
```

Comment: This should work fine http://jsbin.com/divuvu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Did you refer app.js?

Comment: Did you actually included the `app.js` into your page file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to include the `app.js` into the page:

```
<html ng-app="jacksApp">
    <head>
        <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular.js'></script>
        <script src='app.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="mainController">
            <h1>Making an Angular App</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See the documentation for [nomod](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod) error message, it describes pretty well the possible cause.